# robot_state_publisher service not available, but listed in service list

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-humble, rosservice, robot-state-publisher

I'm trying to update a ROS2 package working on Foxy with Turtlebot3 to Humble with Turtlebot4. So I'm sure my code is working there.
While starting a gazebo simulation with a script (that works on Foxy with Turtlebot3) with configurations for Humble and Turtlebot4 everything works fine until the gazebo_ros2_control plugin starts:

start_gazebo terminal:

```
...
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1697466048.417402531] [robot_0.robot_state_publisher]: got segment shell_link
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1697466048.417408752] [robot_0.robot_state_publisher]: got segment tower_sensor_plate
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1697466048.417414864] [robot_0.robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_drop_left
[robot_state_publisher-7] [INFO] [1697466048.417420815] [robot_0.robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_drop_right
...
[add_bot_node-3] response: gazebo_msgs.srv.SpawnEntity_Response(success=True, status_message='SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [robot_0]')
[INFO] [add_bot_node-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 66780]
[gazebo-1] [INFO] [1697464272.745857075] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gazebo-1] [INFO] [1697464272.749156447] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gazebo-1] [INFO] [1697464272.749179150] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gazebo-1] [INFO] [1697464272.749203657] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /opt/ros/humble/share/irobot_create_control/config/control.yaml
[gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1697464273.251784161] [gazebo_ros2_control]: robot_state_publisher service not available, waiting again...
[gazebo-1] [ERROR] [1697464273.751905365] [gazebo_ros2_control]: robot_state_publisher service not available, waiting again...
```

add_robot_node_test terminal:

```
[INFO] [add_bot_node_test-1]: process started with pid [36090]
[INFO] [add_bot_node_test-2]: process started with pid [36092]
[add_bot_node_test-2] [INFO] [1697548144.730713383] [robot_namespace_2.gazeboRobotNode_2]: spawning `robot_2` on namespace `robot_2` at 1.0, 3.0, 0.1
[add_bot_node_test-2] [INFO] [1697548144.731057686] [robot_namespace_2.gazeboRobotNode_2]: Sending service request to `/spawn_entity`
[add_bot_node_test-1] [INFO] [1697548144.735559404] [robot_namespace_1.gazeboRobotNode_1]: spawning `robot_1` on namespace `robot_1` at 0.0, 2.0, 0.1
[add_bot_node_test-1] [INFO] [1697548144.736041017] [robot_namespace_1.gazeboRobotNode_1]: Sending service request to `/spawn_entity`
[add_bot_node_test-2] [INFO] [1697548145.416615228] [robot_namespace_2.gazeboRobotNode_2]: Done! Shutting down add_bot_node.
[add_bot_node_test-2] sdf_file_path:  /opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot4_description/urdf/standard/turtlebot4.urdf.xacro
[add_bot_node_test-2] response: gazebo_msgs.srv.SpawnEntity_Response(success=True, status_message='SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [robot_2]')
[INFO] [add_bot_node_test-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 36092]
```

If I list all services with `ros2 service list` I get :

```
...
/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/list_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically
```

But if I try to call one of the services, it isn't available either.

Did I miss updating something or is the error somewhere else?
Also is it possible to see which request a service server is working on?

Without a robot everything works fine. If I add one robot it seems like services get blocked. So adding a second one doesn't work, as well as the robot_state_publisher isn't available.

after colcon build and sourcing the package:

launch file gazebo:

```
ros2 launch launch_gazebo start_gazebo.launch.py world_name:=arena_large.world
```

```py
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument


def generate_launch_description():
    """Starts a gazebo simulation in the mode, where elements could be added via command line"""

    world_name = LaunchConfiguration('world_name', default='arena_large.world')
    world_directory = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('launch_gazebo'), 'worlds')

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('world_name', description='The name of the world to load, default: turtle.world'),
         
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['gazebo', [world_directory, '/', world_name], '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so'],
            #cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', [world_directory, '/', world_name], '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
            output='screen'
        ),

    ])
```

adding turtlebot4 to it:
`ros2 launch launch_gazebo add_robot_test.launch.py start_index:=1  number_robots:=2 robot:=turtlebot4 x_start:=0 x_dist:=1 y_start:=0 y_start:=2 y_dist:=1`

add_robot_test.py

```py
import sys
import launch_ros.actions
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():
    """Add turtlebot(s) to an already running gazebo simulation."""

    for arg in sys.argv:
        if arg.startswith("start_index:="):  # The start index for the robots number
            start_index = int(arg.split(":=")[1])
        elif arg.startswith("number_robots:="):  # The number of robots to spawn in the world
            number_robots = int(arg.split(":=")[1])
        elif arg.startswith("robot:="):  # The type of robot
            robot = arg.split(":=")[1]
        elif arg.startswith("x_start:="):  # position first robot on x-axis 
            x_start = float(arg.split(":=")[1])
        elif arg.startswith("x_dist:="):  # position first robot on x-axis 
            x_dist = float(arg.split(":=")[1])
        elif arg.startswith("y_start:="):  # position of first robot on y-axis 
            y_start = float(arg.split(":=")[1])
        elif arg.startswith("y_dist:="):  # increment of positions on y-axis 
            y_dist = float(arg.split(":=")[1])
        else:   
            if arg not in ['/opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2',      
                            'launch',
                            'launch_gazebo',
                            'add_robot_test.launch.py']:
                print("Argument not known: '", arg, "'")         

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    for i in range(number_robots):
        
        num = i + start_index

        # add gazebo node
        gazebo_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='launch_gazebo',
            executable='add_bot_node_test',
            namespace=['robot_namespace_', str(num)],
            name=['gazeboRobotNode_', str(num)],
            output='screen',
            arguments=[
                '--robot_name', ['robot_', str(num)],
                '--robot_namespace', ['robot_', str(num)],
                '-x', str(x_start + i * x_dist),
                '-y', str(y_start + i * y_dist),
                '-z', '0.1',
                '--type_of_robot', robot
            ]
        )
        ld.add_action(gazebo_node)

    return ld
```

add_bot_node_test.py:

```py
"""
Script used to spawn a robot in a generic position
"""
import os

import rclpy
import argparse
import xacro
import time 
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SpawnEntity
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def callback(msg):
     print('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)

def main():
    """ Main for spawning robot node """
    # Get input arguments from user
    # argv = sys.argv[1:]

    # Get input arguments from user
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Spawn Robot into Gazebo')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--robot_name', type=str, default='robot',
                        help='Name of the robot to spawn')
    parser.add_argument('-ns', '--robot_namespace', type=str, default='robot',
                        help='ROS namespace to apply to the tf and plugins')
    parser.add_argument('-x', type=float, default=0,
                        help='the x component of the initial position [meters]')
    parser.add_argument('-y', type=float, default=0,
                        help='the y component of the initial position [meters]')
    parser.add_argument('-z', type=float, default=0,
                        help='the z component of the initial position [meters]')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--type_of_robot', type=str, default='waffle_pi',
                        help='the type of robot')            

    args, unkown = parser.parse_known_args()

    # Start node
    rclpy.init()
    node = rclpy.create_node("entity_spawner_"+args.robot_name)

    node.get_logger().debug(
        'Creating Service client to connect to `/spawn_entity`')
    client = node.create_client(SpawnEntity, "/spawn_entity")
    


    node.get_logger().debug("Connecting to `/spawn_entity` service...")
    if not client.service_is_ready():
        client.wait_for_service()
        node.get_logger().debug("...connected!")

    # Get path to the turtlebot4
    if args.type_of_robot == "turtlebot4":
        sdf_file_path = os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('turtlebot4_description'), 'urdf', "standard", 
            'turtlebot4.urdf.xacro')  
        xml = xacro.process_file(sdf_file_path)
        robot_description = xml.toprettyxml(indent='  ')       

        # remapping tf topic 
        root = ET.fromstring(robot_description)
        for plugin in root.iter('plugin'):
            if 'libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so' in plugin.attrib.values():
                break 

            ros_params = plugin.find('ros')
            if ros_params :
                ros_tf_remap = ET.SubElement(ros_params, 'remapping')
                ros_tf_remap.text = '/tf:=/' + args.robot_namespace + '/tf'
        
        robot_description = ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode') 

    print("sdf_file_path: ", sdf_file_path)

    node.get_logger().info('spawning `{}` on namespace `{}` at {}, {}, {}'.format(
        args.robot_name, args.robot_namespace, args.x, args.y, args.z))
   
    request = SpawnEntity.Request()
    request.name = args.robot_name
    request.xml = robot_description   
    request.robot_namespace = args.robot_namespace
    request.initial_pose.position.x = float(args.x)
    request.initial_pose.position.y = float(args.y)
    request.initial_pose.position.z = float(args.z)

    node.get_logger().info("Sending service request to `/spawn_entity`")
    future = client.call_async(request)
    rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(node, future)
    if future.result() is not None:
        print('response: %r' % future.result())
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'exception while calling service: %r' % future.exception())

    node.get_logger().info("Done! Shutting down add_bot_node.")
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Using --verbose showed that I have also a problem with some missing gazebo plugins, but I didn't find a fix online

```
[gazebo-1] [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_create_bumper.so: libgazebo_ros_create_bumper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide instructions for how to reproduce your problem? Isolating the problem to the minimum complete working example [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as suggested in our [question asking checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist)